# Alfresco Share Form based association - node selection

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Is there anyway to restrict which nodes are selectable in Share's object finder popup when selecting a node for an association?
The problem I seem to be having is that I also have some custom types that are specialised versions of cm:content.

```
<type name="mymodel:mytype">
   <parent>cm:content</parent>
```

These seem to have the + button next to them if navigated to within the folder/file navigator window of the object finder/file picker. Are sub-types of `cm:content` always considered to be selectable types for the object finder or is there a way to restrict the selectable types to only allow `cm:content` and not derived types?

Comment: You need to create custom object finder for that.http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/28/alfresco-share-custom-object-finder-js/

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, works as described, once you've got a custom finder wired up correctly you can add the extra params as required.